# c2064 compilation error on updating from msvc v100 to v140 platform toolset

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, macros

I've inherited a project that has to be updated from MSVC platform toolset v100 to v140. Its for the upcoming release of Archicad. All is good except when I set the platform toolset to 140, one of my template function goes wild and got a compilation error:

> C2064 term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

And I got a warning just after this for the same line:

> class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments

The return statement in this block that is pointed by the IDE:

```
template<typename T, typename From>
inline T Convert(From from, const std::locale& locale)
{
    converters::Converter<From, T> conv;
    return conv(from, locale); // <- compilation fails on this line.
}
```

And I have several specializations like this:

```
CONVERTER(API_Guid, GS::Guid, from, locale)
{
   (void)locale;    // It gets optimized away
   return APIGuid2GSGuid(from);
}
```

`CONVERTER` is defined as:

```
#define CONVERTER(From, T, from, locale) \
    template<> \
    struct Converter<From, T> : public std::true_type \
    { \
        inline T operator()(const From& from, const std::locale& locale) const; \
    } ;\
    T Converter<From, T>::operator()(const From& from, const std::locale& locale) const
```

An `operator()` overload for the converter class. I've tried some workarounds like directly defining the Convert functions, but that way I've got linker errors.

Can somebody point out what am I missing? I had no problem compiling it with the older platform toolset. Did Microsoft changed something in the new one?

---

I've sandboxed the converter header, and narrowed it down. Marked the line which uncommented fails to compile, and throws the compilation error mentioned before (C2064).

Here is the reduced Convert.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "Declarations.hpp"
#include "utfcpp\utf8.h"

 #define CONVERTER(From, T, from, locale) \
    template<> \
    struct Converter<From, T> : public std::true_type \
    { \
        inline T operator()(const From& from, const std::locale& locale) const; \
    } ;\
    T Converter<From, T>::operator()(const From& from, const std::locale& locale) const

namespace et
{

    template<typename T>
    inline T Convert(const wchar_t* str, const std::locale& locale = std::locale::classic())
    {
        std::wstring wstr(str);
        return Convert<T>(wstr, locale);
    }

    template<typename T, typename From>
    inline T Convert(From from, const std::locale& locale)
    {
        converters::Converter<From, T> conv;
        return conv(from, locale);
    }


    template<typename From>
    inline std::string S(const From& from)
    {
        return Convert<std::string>(from);
    }


    inline std::string S(const wchar_t* from)      
    {
        // return Convert<std::string>(from); <- This line fails to compile on V140, but does on V100
    }

    namespace converters
    {

        template<typename From, typename T, typename _Enabler1, typename _Enabler2, typename _Enabler3>
        struct Converter : _FALSETYPE_
        {
        };

        template<typename From, typename T>
        struct Converter < From, T, _IF_CONVERTIBLE_(From, T) > : _TRUETYPE_
        {
            inline T operator()(const From& from, const std::locale&) const
            {
                return (T)from;
            }
        };

        CONVERTER(std::string, bool, from, locale)
        {
            (void)locale;   // It gets optimized away
            return et::Convert<bool>(from.c_str());
        }


        CONVERTER(bool, std::string, from, locale)
        {
            (void)locale;   // It gets optimized away
            return from ? std::string("true") : std::string("false");
        }

        CONVERTER(std::string, et::UString, s, locale)
        {
            (void)locale;   // It gets optimized away
            et::UString dest;
            utf8::utf8to16(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(dest));
            return dest;
        }

        CONVERTER(et::UString, std::string, from, locale)
        {
            (void)locale;   // It gets optimized away
            std::string dest;
            utf8::utf16to8(from.begin(), from.end(), std::back_inserter(dest));

            return dest;
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the Declarations.hpp for easier reproduction if anyone interested:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#define _TRUETYPE_  public std::true_type
#define _FALSETYPE_ public std::false_type

#define _IF_CONVERTIBLE_(From, To)  typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<From, To>::value>::type
#define _IF_ARITHMETIC_(A)      typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<A>::value>::type
#define _IF_ARITHMETIC_T_(A, T) typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<A>::value, T>::type

namespace et
{
    template<typename T, typename Enabler = void, typename Blah = void>
    struct IsConvertibleToString : public std::false_type
    {
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct IsConvertibleToString<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value>::type > : public std::true_type
    {
    };

    typedef std::u16string UString;

    template<typename T, typename From>
    T Convert(From from, const std::locale& locale = std::locale::classic());

    template<typename From, typename T>
    struct ConvertFunctor;

    namespace converters
    {

        template<typename From, typename To, typename _Enabler1 = void, typename _Enabler2 = void, typename _Enabler3 = void>
        struct Converter;
    }
}

#define _IF_STRING_CONVERTIBLE_(T) typename std::enable_if<::et::IsConvertibleToString<T>::value>::type
```

The UTF-8 CPP can be obtained from here: [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/utfcpp/).

I'm still interested in suggestions, but I'm 95% sure the that `wchar_t` is the cuplrit.

Comment: Could you mark in your question the line in code those warnings are about? It would be helpful if you could prepare a [complete, minimal file to reproduce the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you are going to stay on SO longer, every party would benefit from that.

Comment: MS is trying to bring its compiler closer to the ANSI standard.  Every version of the compiler since VC6 has had a small set of what they call 'breaking changes', that brings them closer to this goal.

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski I've marked the exact line where the compilation fails.

Comment: I know it's cool to pick on VC 6 as being non-standards-compliant, but the whole bit is a bit silly, considering that VC 6 was released before C++98 was ever standardized. Yes, Microsoft is trying to improve the standards compliance of its compiler, like *all other vendors*.

Comment: You should reduce this *much* further, but anyway, from what I can tell from a very quick glance, `std::string S(const wchar_t* from)` is a plain function, not a template, so it's a point of instantiation for `Convert<std::string>`, which in turn instantiates `converters::Converter<wstring, string>`. However, at that point, `converters::Converter` is only declared, not defined, which is incorrect. Move all the definitions in `namespace converters`, *including the explicit specializations*, above the ones in `namespace et` (you'll need to get rid of the recursive use of `et::Convert<bool>`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing a template<> somewhere...

```
template<>
struct Converter<From, Type> : public std::true_type
{
  inline Type operator()(const From& from, const std::locale& locale) const;
};
// missing template<> here ??  As is, this is not ANSI compliant
Type Converter<From, T>::operator()(const From& from, const std::locale& locale) const { return Type(); }
```

Comment: This was the first thing I spotted, too, but I have a couple of problems with this answer. First, you don't really explain *where* the missing `template<>` is *in his code*. The problem is the definition of the `CONVERTER` macro; perhaps you should mention that somewhere to make the answer more clear? Second, you haven't actually tested this to confirm that it is indeed the answer, so I feel it would be more appropriate to make this type of suggestion in a comment.

Comment: I've added the potentially missing template<> where you indicated, with that `}; \
    template<> \
    Type Converter<..`
I get C2910 error, saying: operator () : cannot be explicitly specialized.

Comment: Also did some research, [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/39129/#msg210981) In the post there is a quote from **C++ Templates the comple guide** which states that **for Class specializations, any definition of member function must be defined as "ordinary" member function.** My code behaves like this.

Comment: I noticed something.  The inline keyword should be in front of the implementation of the function.   And I was wrong.  remove template.  as indicated here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2910

Comment: maybe the placement of inline was the source of your link errors  when trying to define directly the Convert finctions?